# Need help with UV Unwrapping complex geometry

Tags: uv, geometry

I'm working on a modelling project and have unwrapped the whole model except for one section of complex geometry which I'm really not sure how to tackle. I've looked around google for similar geometry unwrapped but to no avail, and have tried several different ways to tackle it but also with no success. Any suggestions on how I should unwrap this geometry would be awesome.

( Relevant geometry is highlighted )

[image: Geometry]

[image: Current UV]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

I'd mark seam the edges going around the shape at the top. the outer one and the inner one. Also the two edges at the sides of that big curved shape could be marked.

Think of uv unwrapping as unfolding your geometry onto a flat sheet of paper. It can help to start by marking the seams of all main edges, and then merging some back together. UV unwrapping can be a tricky process, i'd say don't be scared to mark too many edges!
Otherwise there will be alot of stretching. And you'll see blender will have an easier time unwrapping it for you.

Goodluck!